# Divide by zero error encountered in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this specific part of a query I'm trying to create, I'm getting a "divide by zero" error. I believe this is because I'm trying to divide `ARTran.Qty` by a null. I'm unsure how I can work around this... (I'm using `Cast` as in the next part of the query I'm trying to using this number as a decimal

```
(CASE WHEN ([ARTran].[UOM] LIKE 'EACH') 
         THEN CAST([ARTran].[Qty] AS VARCHAR(30)) 
      ELSE CAST((ARTran.Qty / InventoryItem.UsrLength) AS VARCHAR(30))
 END)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've looked at a few other threads on this, but I'm still not sure how to solve this.

Comment: What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: divide by null would yield `NULL`

Comment: You need to put another check if UsrLength is null or zero then do not do devide operation.

Comment: @Matt has sorted me out, thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you think a divide by zero error would be because you are trying to divide by a null value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` to get around this.

```
(CASE WHEN ([ARTran].[UOM] LIKE 'EACH') 
      THEN CAST([ARTran].[Qty] AS VARCHAR(30)) 
      ELSE CAST((ARTran.Qty / NULLIF(InventoryItem.UsrLength, 0) AS VARCHAR(30))
END)
```

Comment: Does NULLIF here mean that you divide by InventoryItem.UsrLength as long as it is not null, and by 0 if it is null?

Comment: @jarl: no, it's the exact opposite -- we divide by `NULL` if it's 0. The result is `NULL` rather than an error -- `1 / NULL` is legal, `1 / 0` is not.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I see. Thank you for the explanation. Now it makes sense!

Comment: Does anyone else see an attempt to divide by 0 in this answer?

Comment: @DanBracuk: `NULLIF(x, 0)` can never yield `0`, regardless of `x`. It can yield `NULL`, but that's exactly what we want. If you're not convinced, [read the fine manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177562). `NULLIF(x, 0)` is equivalent to `CASE x WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE x END`.